# Can't get the custom message for Apache2 401 authorization error

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, .htpasswd

I have a shared hosting server where each subdomain is in its folder in root. The `www.domain.com` is in the `/www` folder, the `subdomain.domain.com` subdomain is in the `/subdomain` folder, etc.

What I want right now, is to restrict access to `subdomain.domain.com` with a `.htaccess` password, but show a customized message for users who don't have a password. And I can't get Apache2 to read the 401 error document. I have found some common troubleshooting saying that the file has to be readable, which in my case it definitely is.

So, the only two places where I can put the auth file in this configuration, since `/subdomain` is protected, is either under the `/www` folder, or in the root (like `/401.html`), which I have no idea if it makes any difference. But in both cases, those are folders obviously readable by Apache2, because I am using them, I am using the other (main) domain for PHP scripts, and I am getting error logs in the root, the file permissions are the same as on the 404 document (which works), and the owner is the same.

And I don't think my hoster is disabling me from using custom 401 error documents (I am already successfully using custom 404 and 500 documents), because only when I try to specify a 401 document, I get an additional row in my error output that says `Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`. As if it's trying to do it, but there is something else in the way.

What could it be, and what should I try?

**EDIT:**

This is the contents of the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA,L]

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /subdomain/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user

ErrorDocument 404 /tpl/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /tpl/errors/500.php
ErrorDocument 401 /auth_alpha.html
```

And what I'm noticing right now pasting this, is that my 404 messages are an absolute path starting with the `http` address, not the root of the file system, which means that if I start the 401 error document with a `/`, it will try to read it from the same domain? Which makes little sense to me, because it should be an Apache2 directive, not a browser directive, right? Anyway, when I tried putting `../auth_alpha.html` instead of `/auth_alpha.html`, then the browser outputs ONLY the string `../auth_alpha.html` on the page.

Comment: Can you show content of your .htaccess enforcing password

Comment: @anubhava Absolutely, it's in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **exclude** `ErrorDocument` URLs from authentication:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /tpl/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /tpl/errors/500.php
ErrorDocument 401 /auth_alpha.html

Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA,L]

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/(auth_alpha\.html$|tpl/errors/) NO_AUTH

# force auth for everything except ErrorDocument URLs
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /subdomain/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
```

Comment: This worked, but I just want to ask you a little question. Why did it not work to go up a directory and then specify the file from the main domain, which is not under password protection, e.g. `../www/auth_alpha.html`?

Comment: It will switch to main domain only if you use `http://maindomain.com/...` in your error document directive.